# Solve the recurrence of t(n) = t(n/2) + log_2n such that t(1) = 0 and verify using mathematical induction

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, computer-science, proof-explanation

$t(n) = t(n/2) + log_2n$ , such that $t(1) = 0$

and we're assuming in the solution that n is a power of 2 that is $n = 2^m = log_2n$.

Please help me solve this recurrence, I want to verify if my solution $O(log^2n)$ is correct.

Also, how would I verify my answer using mathematical induction on variable m?

Answer (score 0):

If $n = 2^m$,
$t(2^m)
=t(2^{m-1})+m
$.

Let
$s(m) = t(2^m)
$.

Then 
$s(m) = s(m-1)+m
$.
From this,
$s(m) = \frac12 m(m+1)
$,
so
$t(n)
=t(2^m) 
= m(m+1)
=\log_2(n)(\log_2(n)+1)
=\Theta(\log_2^2(n))
$.

Comment: Thanks for verifying the recurrence! Do you know how I would verify my answer using induction on variable m?